# How to position heading (h1) placed on a background image and centered according to it outside of its container

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-position

In a desktop version I have a background image and h1. H1 is centered according to the image and below I have some content.
I've created codepen to visually describe (I used color placeholder instead of an image) - [what I have](http://codepen.io/m0t0r/pen/YXrRLV?editors=110)

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
</div>

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  background: #ddd;
}
h1 {
  position:absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top:50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0;
}
```

In mobile version I need to place h1 ouside of the image and apply some spacing on top and bottom. 
I've created another codepen where I changed markup to show what I need to achive but using CSS - [what I need but with CSS](http://codepen.io/m0t0r/pen/vOeQjZ?editors=110)

How to achive the result as in the second codepen but with CSS ?

Main points:

- h1 has to be placed to an image and centered according to it in desktop version
- h1 has to be ouside of the image and have some top and bottom spacing in mobile version.

Comment: You can use `media queries` to achieve this

Comment: Oh yes, I know that. My question is how to structure html and apply CSS positioning in order to get desired effect.

Comment: use display: table? - http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/ew2ctyvy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/mq3n7we4/3/

Used `@media (min-width: 481px)` to position the `h1` above the `image`.

Answer (score 1):

Resize the browser window <= 480px

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  background: #ddd;
}

h1 {
  position:absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top:50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) 
{
  h1{
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 300px;
    float: left;
    transform: none;
    left: 0;
  }
  
  p{
    margin-top: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
</div>
<div class="content">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur tempore veniam, odit odio dolor mollitia pariatur, nihil! Quis quae reprehenderit deserunt vitae nostrum maxime, enim cupiditate illum optio, fugit suscipit. Possimus laboriosam praesentium fuga, labore quia quo minima nulla libero qui amet vitae rerum veritatis alias non cumque laudantium nesciunt.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but not exactly what I need. If you resize up to 400px then word in the second line covers content. I assume h1 has to have padding (margin) to control top and bottom spacing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little new to the forums so I dont really know how to paste the code properly however I think this is what you are looking for. The main difference is the creation of a desktop and a mobile class that way you can control when they show up on the screen. The idea is similar to the way bootstrap 3 uses the visible-xs and hidden-xs class. That way you can control the different views. It's not the most elegant of solutions but I think it does what you need it to do.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  background: #ddd;
}

h1 {
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.desktop{
 display:none;
}

@media screen and (min-width:481px){
 .desktop{
  display:block;
 }
 .desktop h1{
  position:absolute;
   text-align: center;
   top:50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   margin: 0;
 }
 
 .mobile{
  display:none;
 }
}

</style>
</head>
<body>


</body>
<div class="container"><div class="desktop"><h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1></div></div>
<div class="mobile"><h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1></div>
<div class="content">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur tempore veniam, odit odio dolor mollitia pariatur, nihil! Quis quae reprehenderit deserunt vitae nostrum maxime, enim cupiditate illum optio, fugit suscipit. Possimus laboriosam praesentium fuga, labore quia quo minima nulla libero qui amet vitae rerum veritatis alias non cumque laudantium nesciunt.</p>
</div>

</html>
```